# Facebook authentication needs additional refresh to log in user

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I recently updated the Facebook PHP SDK to version 3.x.x after my earlier code stopped working. Now, when the user logs in, the page refreshes but still shows the Facebook login button. If I refresh it one more time then it logs in the user. Any idea what is going on? has anyone else faced a similar problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "refreshing" the page, then the problem is not the php sdk, is the javascript you are using. Could you please provide more info about your problem? Are you experiencing the problem in all browsers? are you using http/https correctly? Please be more specific.